# Checkbox height coudn't change using MoveWindow

Tags: winapi

I'm developing a simple application.

I have created a checkbox , and I set it's dimensions using MoveWindow.
top , right , left positions are working fine, but the problem is , it does not
respond for correct bottom value. In other words I couldn't adjust it's height.

```
static void SetCheckboxSinhalaDimensions(HWND hwndCheckboxSinhala)
{
  double right = 0;
  double left  = TEXT_BOX_RIGHT_MARGIN * main_window_width ;
  double top = TEXT_BOX_TOP_MARGIN * main_window_height ;

  int cychar = HIWORD (GetDialogBaseUnits ()) ;
  double bottom = top+ 2*cychar; // I've used 1.5 , 1 , 0.5 and even 0.2 here
                             // but it never changed.
  MoveWindow (hwndCheckboxSinhala, right,top, left,bottom,TRUE);
}
```

This is how it look like on main window.
[image]

Any workaround on this issue?
Or something that I'm missing?

Comment: What happens when you specify an exact pixel value?

Comment: using such as 20+TOP ? , I'd tried it. It didn't worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got the parameters to `MoveWindow` wrong.  It takes left, top, width and height; not right, top, left and bottom.

```
BOOL WINAPI MoveWindow(
  _In_  HWND hWnd,
  _In_  int X,
  _In_  int Y,
  _In_  int nWidth,
  _In_  int nHeight,
  _In_  BOOL bRepaint
);
```

Comment: Yes sir you absolutely right ! I don't know why I missed that. may be that's why I need peer reviewing guy.